# Finding constant in geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Adding constant $c$ to variables $x, y, z$ yields first three successive terms of geometric sequence, i.e. $a_1 = x + c, a_2 = y + c, a_3 = z + c$. Now, let $x = 2, y = 16, z = 58$. How can one find $c$, so that after that one can find quotient $q$ and sum $S_4$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$\dfrac{16+c}{2+c}=\dfrac{58+c}{16+c}$